# Is there a way to link a label and date field when being dynamically added to a form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datepicker

I'm not sure if what I am doing is possible and if it is, what the best way to go about it is. I have a WinForm dynamically creating controls, depending on the type pre-selected by the user. This includes text boxes, date fields, dropdowns, and others. When a date field is created, I want to add a label that displays the age next to it. With what I have now, I can display the age when the form loads, but I need a solution on how to get the label to update if the date is changed?
I have tried creating a leave handler for the datepicker, but that does not work because it does not have control of each datepicker control, just the last one created.

EDIT:I'm going to share some code that I am using now. This function is calculating the age and creating the label that will go next to the datepicker.

```
Private Sub getAge()
    If ucDP.Text = "" OrElse ucDP.Text = "  /  /" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim currentDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim zeroTime As DateTime = New DateTime(1, 1, 1)
    Dim selectedDate As DateTime = New DateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(ucDP.Text).Year, Convert.ToDateTime(ucDP.Text).Month, Convert.ToDateTime(ucDP.Text).Day)
    Dim dateNow As DateTime = New DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day)
    lblAge = New Label
    If (selectedDate > dateNow) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim span As TimeSpan = dateNow - selectedDate
    Dim years As Integer = ((zeroTime + span).Year - 1)
    lblAge.Text = "Age: " & years
    lblAge.Location = New Drawing.Point(ucDP.Location.X + 122, ucDP.Location.Y + 2)
    lblAge.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.MidnightBlue
    lblAge.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9.75!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))

    gb.Controls.Add(lblAge)

End Sub
```

And I just have the sub executing in the ucDP event handler.

EDIT 2: Adding how I create the datepicker control

```
ElseIf datatype = "date" Then
            ucDP = New MSCtrlCore.ucDatePicker()
            ucDP.FutureDateEnabled = True
            ucDP.Name = "ucdp" & pkIOCI
            ucDP.Location = New Drawing.Point((gb.Width / 2) + 80, lbl.Location.Y + 3)
            ucDP.Format = "MM/DD/YYYY"
            ucDP.Size = New Drawing.Size(120, 26)
            ucDP.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Right

            sql = String.Format("SELECT Answer FROM OtherCoverageAnswers WHERE ISNULL(IsArchived, 0) = 0 AND fk_InsuredOtherCoverageInfo = {0} AND fk_Insured = {1}", pkIOCI, insuredKey)
            Try
                GetScalar(sql, strValue)
                If strValue = String.Empty OrElse strValue = "0" Then
                    ucDP.Text = ""
                Else
                    ucDP.Text = strValue
                End If
            Catch ex As System.Exception
            End Try
            AddHandler ucDP.Leave, AddressOf ucDP_Leave
            gb.Controls.Add(ucDP)
```

Comment: Use the tag property of the datepicker to store the label control.

Comment: If your controls are *associated*, you can build a UserControl that contains both a DateTimePicker and a Label. So you have all the *logic* in one place. It's also easier to customize, localize etc.

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: @Jimi I have the datetimepicker and the label in the same groupbox already, but i cannot maintain control of all the datetimepickers that i have in different group boxes.

Comment: A UserControl is not related to a GroupBox or other similar containers. A UserControl is a single UI element that can contain different, distinct standard controls, all functioning as a single unit. So, you can have a custom logic that creates a correlation between all the internal controls. An event, handler in this simple case, will do. Your UserControl can expose a public property that allows to change the internal `DateTimePicker.Value` and use the DTP `ValueChanged` event to set a `Label.Text` (or perform any other action is required).

Comment: @Jimi I am using ucDatePicker. ValueChanged is not part of that, but i am using ucDP.leave and ucDP.DateChanged and neither of them are going off when i change any of the dates.

Comment: I know of a `UCDatePicker` for WPF and one for `ASP.Net`. I don't know of one for WinForms, so I cannot tell you how that control works, but I assume it must raise an event when the DateTime value changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen well, because I'm putting waaay too much time in this answer. Ok I love this but still, please don't waste my time and learn at least one thing, even if this is not the answer you're looking for.

We'll do what jimi said and create a custom control, which will keep the operational logic all in one place.

First, right-click on your project and add a new user control:

[image: Right click here]

[image: Add a new user control]

Name it whatever you want. I'm naming mine `AgeDateTimePickerControl`:

[image: Create a new user control]

Now design your new control. It's as easy as designing a form:

[image: Design the user control]

You can code properties, events, and this sort of thing into your custom control. I customed mine by copying your age calcul logic (I changed it to a simpler one because this is just an example) and writing it into the `ValueChanged` event of the DateTimePicker. I also coded 2 properties: Age (read only) and birth date (read and write). I made properties so that later, when I'll use the control inside a form, I'll be able to access them easily.

Here's how the code looks:

```
Public Class AgeDateTimePickerControl
    Private _age As Integer

    'You can create properties for your custom control to access them from your form later
    Public ReadOnly Property Age() As String
        Get
            Return _age
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property BirthDate() As DateTime
        Get
            Return DateTimePicker1.Value
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            DateTimePicker1.Value = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'You can use events just like in a form
    Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
        If (DateTimePicker1.Value < Date.Today) Then
            _age = Date.Today.Year - DateTimePicker1.Value.Year
            Label1.Text = "Age: " & _age
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Once you're finished with your new tool, save your project and rebuild it (if you don't build your own control, Visual Studio will not let you use it in the form designer).

[image: REBUILD]

Now you can drag and drop it from your toolbox. What? You want to add it programmatically? Sure, you can also do that. But look at the toolbox first! You just designed a new control!

[image]

Now, to test the business logic of your new control, drag and drop it into your form, compile and try it. The one I just coded was fun but maybe not exactly what you want, so tweak and code until you're satisfied.

Then add it programmatically to your form just as you used to do with the controls you were using before.

Isn't life beautiful?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make this little tutorial. I will look at this in the morning and comment on how it goes.

Comment: Glad you liked it!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the labels added in a list. Then when the DateTimePicker value changes, you can update each label's text. This allows for multiple labels.

```vb
Private ageLabels As New List(Of Label)()

Private Sub getAge()
    If ucDP.Text = "" OrElse ucDP.Text = "  /  /" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim currentDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim zeroTime As DateTime = New DateTime(1, 1, 1)
    Dim selectedDate As DateTime = New DateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(ucDP.Text).Year, Convert.ToDateTime(ucDP.Text).Month, Convert.ToDateTime(ucDP.Text).Day)
    Dim dateNow As DateTime = New DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day)
    lblAge = New Label
    If (selectedDate > dateNow) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim span As TimeSpan = dateNow - selectedDate
    Dim years As Integer = ((zeroTime + span).Year - 1)
    lblAge.Text = "Age: " & years
    lblAge.Location = New Drawing.Point(ucDP.Location.X + 122, ucDP.Location.Y + 2)
    lblAge.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.MidnightBlue
    lblAge.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9.75!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))

    gb.Controls.Add(lblAge)
    ageLabels.Add(l)

End Sub

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    ageLabels.ForEach(Sub(l) l.Text = $"{DateTimePicker1.Value}")
    ' fix logic to show age instead of date :)
End Sub
```

Comment: This was still not changing the age when I would change the date in the datepicker.

Comment: @josh42 well, it should. I just added it to your supplied code.

Comment: When I use your code, there are a few issues. The first is that I am not sure where you are getting the "l" variable that you are adding to the ageLabels control and calling in the valuechanged event handler. Second, even though I am getting the leave event handler to fire every time, it is still returning the value from the last created datepicker, rather than the one I am leaving.

Comment: I also added the code i am using to create the datepicker control